# Rails link to dinâmico

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller

Estou com a seguinte dúvida, no meu controller tem uma variavel que pega qual o modelo que o cara está vindo e envia para  a view.

Gostaria de criar um link a partir desta variavel tipo: link_to @link(variavel: @variavel), nesta parte o sistema é muito dinâmico e gostaria de poder mostrar um link de volta ao modelo que o teria invocado a criação.

Answer (score 0):

No exemplo abaixo eu estou enviando o caminho de origem para a próxima página, você pode fazer isso usando partial com o atributo [locals](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials).

`<%= render partial: 'form', locals: {path_origem: 'VALOR_DO_PATH_ORIGEM'} %>`

Aqui abaixo o `path_origem` tem o valor VALOR_DO_PATH_ORIGEM, dessa forma você consegue voltar para a página de origem.

`<%= f.submit 'voltando', path_origem %>`